# How to tell React ts component that a nullable state is guaranteed not to be null so that we don't have to confirm over and over?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Situation:

1. In a React TS component, there's a nullable state (initial value is set to null)
2. `useEffect` inside the component guarantees that the state is not null (because the logic of the `useEffect` redirects users back if the value is null)
3. Everytime I use `someState` in the component I have to write code to make sure that the `someState` is not null (e.g. if (someState !== null) doSomething) otherwise TS complains.
   Is there any possible way to tell(or set) the component that a state is not null for sure so that I don't have to write if state all the time when I use the state?

If you have a special remedy for it, please let me know.

```js
// inside a component
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState<ISomeState | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const res = getSomeStateValue();
    // let's say the function `getSomeStateValue()` is async 
    // and **redirect user if the value for `someState` is null** 
    //so literally when a user is in this component, someState will never be null
},[])

// in some function
const someFunction = () => {
  const aState = someState.someKey // this line throws error 'someState can be null` and I have to write like below not to have error everytime I use someState
  if (someState !== null) // do something with the `someState` and the null error is now gone
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use what's known as optional chaining to handle null (objects) gracefully. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Since I don't have the full context in which you are using `someState`, allow me to contrive an example. Let's say `someState` is an object that has a property called `someKey` which in turn, has a value.

```
someState: { someKey: someValue }
```

If you tried to reference `someState.someKey`, you may get a Typescript error because of the fact that someState is initially set to null and therefore, at some point, can be null.

You could solve this via optional chaining, or simply put, by placing a question mark after the object whose potential null (or undefined) value is causing the issue: `someState?.someValue`

Let me know if this helps clear up your Typescript errors.

Comment: The explanation from the link of MDN above: `The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.` literally describes my case. Thanks.

Comment: I wish later on the React team create functionality that a component can recognize a state's guaranteed state based on the behavior of the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the state is null or not. If null then fetch data.

```
// inside a component
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState<ISomeState | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if(!someState) {
        const res = getSomeStateValue();
        setSomeState(res);
    }
    
    
},[someState])
```

Comment: I'm asking about how not to write `if (someState !== null) // code with someState` every time I use the `someState` inside the component because using `someState` directly throws 'someState can be null' type error so every time when I use the `someState` I need to write additional codes to tell TS that it's not null. (As I explained, when a user is in the component `someState` cannot be null because the user will be redirected to outside of the component